# Get href value Json linking with HAL

Tags: json, href, hal

Hi I try to figure out how to get the value of a link in the response of a request of this type :

```
 {
   "_links" : {
            "self" : {"href" : "https://link.net/someInfo" },

            "profile" : {"href" : "https://link.net"},

  ==>       "https://link.net/item1" : {"href" : "https://thelinkIwanttohave.net"},

            "https://link.net/item2" : {"href" : "https://link.net"},
   },
   "reference" : "723bb02f-8e24-11e6-9184-000000000000"
}
```

Following this (http://blog.stateless.co/post/13296666138/json-linking-with-hal)
if I want to get the self href value. I can get it through :

```
json._links.self.href
```

But how can I get the href value of https://link.net/item1.
If I type :

```
json._links.https://link.net/item1.href
```

I got an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token. I can't find example of this.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors), you can access javascript properties in two ways:

```
object.property
object["property"]
```

So in your case try:

```
json._links['https://link.net/item1'].href
```